# finding days between depending on various conditions

Tags: teradata

Lets say the data is like this

```
cust_id visit_dt    Purchase_dt item    FIRST_Purchase_dt       
1234    1/11/2017   1/12/2017   Big     1/1/2015            
1234    1/18/2018   1/19/2018   Big     1/1/2015                     
1567    1/11/2008   1/12/2008   Big     3/27/2007                    
1345    1/3/2006                Small   1/2/2006                     
1345    1/24/2008   1/24/2008   Big     1/2/2006                     
1579    1/24/2009               Medium  5/6/2006
```

I want to calculate days between like calculation  [image]
Days between should be calculated like this-

a) if there is no duplicate Cust_id then it is  visit_dt-First_Purchase dt or the first duplicate cust_id when sorted by visit_dt.

b) if there is duplicate then visit_dt-Previous(purchase_dt) if it exists else visit_dt-previous(visit_dt). 
This happens as when the item is small or medium then there is no purchase dt.

```
 select  cust_id,visit_dt,Purchase_dt, item,FIRST_Purchase_dt,visit_dt-FIRST_Purchase_dt as Days_BTW from table
```

this works only for first condition not sure how to implement the second condition

Comment: But SAS has a CASE and COALESCE(a,b) is just a shortcut for  CASE WHEN a IS NOT NULL THEN a ELSE b END. And why implement in SAS when the database can calculate it much faster?

Comment: Right got confused.How to capture previous (visit_dt or purchase_dt) for a duplicate cust_id

Comment: In TD16.10 there's `LAG(visis_dt) OVER (PARTITITON BY cust_id ORDER BY visit_dt)`, before it can be written as `MAX(visis_dt) OVER (PARTITITON BY cust_id ORDER BY visit_dt ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)`